# Using case statements with notify in Puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

```
class mymodule::scripts::os_check {
  case $operatingsystem  {
    /(?i-mx:centos)/: { notify("You are using CentOS")}
    /(?i-mx:.*)/: { notify("You are using non-CentOS OS") }
  }
}
```

Why does this run without error, but not display either notify (on a server where the operatingsystem fact == CentOS)?

I am running this as a standalone script using puppet apply os-check.pp and just see the catalog run notify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Craig's excellent answer, you need to:

include mymodule::scripts::os_check

Edit:  Otherwise, you are just defining a class, not instantiating it.

Comment: Can you show sample code please?

Comment: Thanks for the hat-tip - this is more likely a "correct" answer on reflection, the lack of output is a symptom of not including/instantiating a class.

Comment: @Gregg - combine the include from my post with the code from Craig's post into one file:

`class mymodule::scripts::os_check {
  case $::operatingsystem  {

    'CentOS': {
      notify {'You are using CentOS': }
    }

    default: {
      notify {'You are using non-CentOS OS': }
    }
  }
}

include mymodule::scripts::os_check`

Comment: This was the correct answer.  I was confused about class instantiate vs define.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
class mymodule::scripts::os_check {
  case $::operatingsystem  {

    'CentOS': {
      notify {'You are using CentOS': }
    }

    default: {
      notify {'You are using non-CentOS OS': }
    }
  }
}
```

A few points, in no particular order, with references in parentheses where appropriate:

- You should be using single quotes for all strings that do not contain variable interpolation ([Puppet Lint](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/double_quoted_strings/)).
- It's always better to match actual values when you know them - is there any specific reason why you're trying to match on a regex?
- The `operatingsystem` fact should be matched by using the top-level namespace variable `$::operatingsystem` ([Puppet Lint](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/variable_scope/))
- You should always provide a default option for any case statement ([Puppet Lint](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/case_without_default/))
- Your `notify` syntax is wrong, you should instantiate a notify *resource* rather than trying to call it as a function ([Puppet Type Reference](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#notify))

Comment: That also gives me the same result `notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds
`  I do appreciate all of the insight, you have some good points.

Comment: PS, I am also a bassplayer.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with a pastebin/gist of the output of `puppet agent --test --debug`?